# Facebook graph api Post Id incorrect for update profile picture post

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get Facebook user post feed using the following API `https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v7.0/user/feed`

If the user update the profile picture more than one time like the following example:

```
"story": "XX XX updated his profile picture.",
"created_time": "2020-08-04T11:47:11+0000",
"updated_time": "2020-08-04T11:47:11+0000",
"id": "UID_POSTID_1",

"story": "XX XX updated his profile picture.",
"created_time": "2020-08-03T10:40:11+0000",
"updated_time": "2020-08-03T10:40:11+0000",
"id": "UID_POSTID_2",
```

So only the post id of the last profile picture update will work:

```
www.facebook.com/UID_POSTID_1 #work
www.facebook.com/UID_POSTID_2 #Not working - Sorry, this content isn't available right now
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you getting both those post IDs in the same API request, or are we talking about previous responses that you have cached or something?

Comment: same api request

Comment: I guess these posts “expire” somehow, no one wants to see a dozen such posts in their feed, if a friend keeps changing their profile picture all day long. That the API would still return them then, could be considered a bug - you can file a report under https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs, if you like, although I doubt this will get high priority.

Comment: the post isn't expired, its still exist of user feed

Comment: Can you view it on its own then? And if so, is that URL the same as your `www.facebook.com/UID_POSTID_2` then?

Comment: Hi, Yes, I can see the post on the user feed - the POSTID is diffrent from what I got from API